# How do I execute these moves?

Tags: ps3, ufc-undisputed-2010

I'm having difficulties with moves in UFC3. For example, stepping kicks

step + L1 + square

I tried many times and never got to do it. I don't understand what am I supposed to do. Another thing is

cage + R3 (submission defense), what does that mean? I tried this as well, never succeeded.

Comment: I have never played UFC3, but you may just be pushing the buttons wrong... Make sure that you hold down all of the buttons, don't just push them in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting far away and run towards your opponent then use L1 and square - this should at least allow you to see the move.  Make sure your in the correct range to be able to execute the move (i.e. striking, clinch range, etc.) the step moves are tough because you can't be too far away from the opponent, and often times you end up too close after the step.

The cage one simply means you either have to be right next to the cage, or up against it (depends on the move) and then use the R3.